# Replacing bulb in Janeiro surface mount ceiling light (not LED)

Tags: lighting, ceiling, bulb, mount

We had these Janeiro flush mount light fixtures installed 7 years ago - not LED. M10122 is the model number I believe. The light went out and we tried to remove the dome but it did not come off easily with twisting, pulling, turning each way...and the whole fixture fell from the ceiling leaving a big hole. I have not been able to find the installation instructions online and the store we bought it from is no longer in business. I am looking for the electrician who installed it but cannot find him either. I am wondering if we have a faulty fixture? Or if the electrician sealed it with glue instead of using screws? It is not LED so I assume there should be a way to remove the dome to replace bulbs. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Photos of your actual situation would be great.

Comment: You need to clarify what your question is. Ask yourself, what do you want random internet people on this website to tell you? This sounds like you are venting... so, if your question is, "how do i remove the dome to replace the lightbulb and then how do i remount it?" edit your post with that question and you absolutely need to include a picture of your light hanging off the ceiling showing the state of the mounting point or hole left behind (either in one photo, or several if you can't get it all in one shot).

Answer (score 1):

I see you're new to the site. Let me help you make a better post. This is unfocused and needs some work. [Please review this article](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and bear in mind a question like your's if not edited often end up getting closed for a number of reasons described [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Right now, your post is more about venting frustration than soliciting specific advice for a specific action (leading to your desired outcome or end state).

As it stands, you have asked three questions, and I will give you answers to those questions to demonstrate the problem with your post. Please don't be intimidated, as we want to help you learn how to turn this into a good question because there are bound to be other people out there with the same problem who you will help by asking your question.

So as it stands, your questions will not help you replace your bulb or get your light mounted again. You have not asked the right question(s) or given us the right information to get you there. If you see where I'm coming from after reading my answers to your questions below, you will need to edit your post with a more appropriate question or questions if these answers aren't what you need to solve your problem:

---

Your questions:

1. > I am wondering if we have a faulty fixture?

It is impossible to tell with the information you've provided. Given what you've described, nothing indicates fault with the fixture or the installation: It has functioned without issue for seven years and you claim it is not LED (though you don't know what type of bulb it has), which means that is great performance out of a fluorescent or incandescent bulb assuming regular use; and, it's mounting failed because you didn't know how to properly remove the globe and your actions damaged the mounting (or maybe you just don't know how it sets back onto the mounting and you don't realize it's fine, but since you haven't given us any photos we have to assume you describing it as damaged is accurate).

2. > Or if the electrician sealed it with glue instead of using screws?

Do you see glue? We have no way of telling given the information you've provided. However, chances are strong that you just don't know how to pop it off.

3. > Anyone have any ideas?

Sure, here's my idea (I'm going to be cheeky): Try asking a better question, one that is targeted at the solution or end state you want to get to. Ask us a question that is focused on what you want to do about your situation.

That said, the answer you're probably looking for is this: If twisting doesn't work, and there are no visible screws, and you're not married to the fixture so if you damage it (as it sounds like you might already have done), try approaching it as a pressure fit or captured component. See if you can pry it out (gently). As for remounting it, you will need give us more information as to what state the mounting hardware or substrate is in right now. Chances are you can fix it.

Good luck, and I hope you find this helpful not offensive! I mean this to be encouraging, not insulting!! Your post is almost there with getting us the right information, it just needs a little more work!

[Also, here you go](https://s1.img-b.com/build.com/mediabase/specifications/illuminating_experiences/1252069/illuminating-experiences-m10122-specification-sheet.pdf): the manufacturer is Illuminating Experiences, the product line is Janeiro, the type is 100W incandescent, and the globe is counterclockwise twist lock.

If this is your solution, please click the checkmark to accept this answer.